# Android- parceling object that contains other objects?

Tags: android, parcelable

This is an issue I have been grappling with as an Android beginner. I cannot find any good tutorials online on dealing with parceling complex objects. All the examples I've seen deals with simple classes that only holds primitives.

However, in my case I have a complicated Maze object that aggregates other objects.

For instance, here is my Maze class:

```
 public class Maze {
    int mazew; // width of maze
    int mazeh; // height of maze
    Cells mazecells ; // maze as a matrix of cells which keep track of the location of walls
    Distance mazedists ; // a matrix with distance values for each cell towards the exit
    Cells seencells ; // a matrix with cells
    BSPNode rootnode ; // a binary tree type search data structure to quickly locate a subset of segments
    ...
```

And here is the Cells class:

```
public class Cells {

  private int width;
  private int height ;
  private int[][] cells;
  ...
```

How would I go about parceling an object such as Maze that contains other objects? What if those aggregate objects also contains other objects. I can't imagine trying to parse an entire chain of objects if I had to do nested parcelables! Any advice on how to pass `Maze` object between Activities in the best manner is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the reason you want to make a complex object Parcelable is to share it across activities/fragments then you might consider using a [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) instead. EventBus lets you pass plain Java objects around avoiding the work of implementing Parcelable for every single object the complex object depends on.

Alternatively, Serializable is usually a drop-in replacement for Parcelable if performance is not a factor. Using Serializable is usually trivial code change of adding `implements Serializable` to your classes. See [Parcelable vs Serializable](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/) for some details on performance differences.

Answer (score 2):

Just make all objects you want to pass along Parcelable (by implementing [Parcelable interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)) and since each Parcelable object parcels itself and all its that's basically all you need to do (and to bother :)

Comment: It looks like he doesn't want to do the work to make everything parcelable though.

Comment: what one wants and what he can get can sometimes be completely different :)

Comment: I've decided to use parcelabe, but I can't find an example where someone is reading/writing in an object as opposed to a primitive.

Comment: Not sure I am getting your question? If your class' member is an object, then to parcel it its class must implement Parcelable. And if so all you need to do is to call `writeParcelable($object, 0)` in your `writeToParcel()` method.